# encrypt files using a variant of Vernam Cipher in C language

Tags: c, file, vigenere-cipher, encryption

I'm coding this program that allows you to encrypt files using vernam cipher in C language. I would be glad if you could inspect my code and tell me if I can make some improvements to it or if there are any error.

The request they gave me is:

> *The goal is to develop a simple application that allows you to encrypt files using a variant of the Vernam cipher, here called bvernan. The proposed algorithm exploits a simple property of the binary operator XOR: (A XOR B) XOR B = A Given a sequence of k-bytes b0 ... bk-1 (called key), the encoding function of a sequence of bytes d0 ... dN, the encoding / decoding function follows the following simple procedure. The sequence d0 ... dN is first divided into N / k blocks (integer division), D0, ..., D [(N / k) -1] each of which consists of exactly k bytes (apart from the 'last sequence which, obviously, may contain a smaller number of bytes). Subsequently each sequence Dj = dj, 0 ... dj, k-1 is transformed into the sequence D'j = d'j, 0 ... d'j, k-1 such that for each i: d'j, i = b (j + i) mod k XOR dj, i That is, the byte in position i of block j is placed in XOR with the byte (j + i) mod k of the key. The output sequence will then be obtained from the juxtaposition of the sequences D'0, ..., D '[(N / k) -1].*

This is the code:

#### file main.c

```
#include "encode.h"

int main (int argc ,char** argv){
    if(argc!=4){
        printf("Usage: bvernan keyfile inputfile outputfile \n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    Key_t* key=openKey(argv[1]);
    
    Register_t* file=openFile(argv[2],argv[3],key->lenght);
    encode(file,key);
    closeRegister(file);
    freeKey(key);
    printf("Success!\n");
}
```

#### file encode.c

```
#include "encode.h"

int encode (Register_t* file, Key_t* key ){
    while(readF(file)>0){
        encodeDivision(file->buffer,file->bufferLenght,key);
        writeF(file);
    }
}
void encodeDivision (unsigned char* block,long lenght,Key_t*key){
    for(int i=0;i<lenght;i++){
        block[i]=block[i]^key->buffer[i];
    }
}
```

#### file encode.h

```
#include "key.h"
#include "register.h"

int encode (Register_t* file, Key_t* key );
void encodeDivision (unsigned char* block,long lenght,Key_t*key);
```

#### file key.c

```
#include "key.h"
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>


long keySize (FILE* file){
    fseek (file,0,SEEK_END);
    long size=ftell(file);
    rewind (file);
    return size;
}
Key_t* openKey(char* path){
    Key_t* kFile= malloc (sizeof(Key_t));
    FILE*file= fopen(path,"rb");
    kFile->lenght=keySize(file);
    kFile->buffer= malloc(kFile->lenght);
    fread(kFile->buffer,1,kFile->lenght,file);
    fclose(file);
    return kFile;
}
void freeKey (Key_t* key ){
free (key->buffer);
free (key);
}
```

#### file key.h

```
typedef struct Key
{
    unsigned char* buffer; 
    long lenght;
} Key_t; 

Key_t* openKey(char* path);
void freeKey (Key_t*);
```

#### file register.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "register.h"

Register_t* openFile (char* inPath,char* outPath,long bufferLenght){
    Register_t* file = malloc (sizeof(Register_t));
    file->buffer= malloc(bufferLenght);
    file->bufferLenght=bufferLenght;
    file->fdIn= fopen(inPath,"rb");
    file->fdOut= fopen(outPath,"wb");
    if(file->fdOut==NULL || file->fdIn==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
        return file;
}
int readF (Register_t* file){
    int readbyte = fread(file->buffer,1,file->bufferLenght,file->fdIn);
    file->bufferLenght=readbyte;
    return readbyte;
}
int writeF (Register_t* file){
    int writebyte = fwrite(file->buffer,1,file->bufferLenght,file->fdOut);
    return writebyte;
}
void closeRegister (Register_t* file){
    free(file->buffer);
    fclose(file->fdIn);
    fclose(file->fdOut);
    free(file);
}
```

#### file register.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Register
{
    unsigned char *buffer;
    FILE *fdIn;
    FILE *fdOut;
    long bufferLenght;
} Register_t;

Register_t *openFile(char *inPath, char *outPath, long bufferLenght);
int readF(Register_t *);
int writeF(Register_t *);
void closeRegister(Register_t *);
```

#### file Makefile

```
all: bvernan    

bvernan: encode.o key.o main.o register.o
    gcc -o bvernan $^

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $<

clean:
    rm *.o bvernan
```

Answer (score 3):

> if I can make some improvements to it or if there are any error.

**Lack of error checking**

`fopen(), malloc(), ftell(), fread()`, (all I/O functions), etc. deserve to have their return values checked for errors.

In particular when a file may fail to open or memory fail to allocate, handle such cases to not forget the other. e. g.: do not forget to `fclose()`, or `fclose()` twice when memory allocation failed.

Gracefully handling errors and still maintaining nice code flow is challenging.

**Lack of comments**

*some* comments would help, especially in .h files.  A header files is sometimes all a user sees (or cares to see) .

**.h files**

Missing code guards.

Reduce namespace scattering.  Recommend a common prefix per objects in a .h file

**Types**

`long` OK for most files sizes.  `size_t` better for array sizing and indexing.

`long lenght ... for(int i=0;i<lenght;i++)` --> `i` and `length` should be the same type: `size_t`.

**Style**

Use an auto formatter to improve code appearance at less time cost.

**Tolerant free**

Note that `free(NULL)` is well defined.  Do so like-wise for `freeKey(NULL);`

**Spelling**

`lenght` --> `length`.

**Spaces**

Style is very dense left=to=right.  Some spaces would help.

```
// block[i]=block[i]^key->buffer[i];
block[i] = block[i] ^ key->buffer[i];
```

**Include order**

For xxx.c, I recommend including xxx.h first, to help test its ability to stand alone.

```
// file register.c

#include "register.h"  // Put first
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Unclear why `register.h` has `#include <stdlib.h>`.  Excessive `#include` files in a .c file have their place and are not so much a timely concern.  (Some coding environments offer a check.)

.h file should use a minimal set.

**Naming**

Consider using the same *case* and order for the names `key.c, Key_t` --> `key.c, key_t`. `keySize(), openKey()` --> `keySize(), keyOpen()`.

**Allocating**

Rather than size by *type*, size by the referenced object.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// ptr = malloc(sizeof(hopefully_the_right_type));
ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);
```

---

***Simplistic* error handling examples**

```
FILE*file = fopen(path,"rb");
if (file == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file <%s> for reading.\n", path);
  exit EXIT_FAILURE;
}

Key_t* kFile = malloc(sizeof *kFile);
if (kFile == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.\n");
  exit EXIT_FAILURE;
}

long size = ftell(file);
if (size == -1 || size > SIZE_MAX) {
  fprintf(stderr, "File size problem %ld.\n", size);
  exit EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

**Allow `freeKey(NULL)`**

This allows calls to `freeKey(k)` without first checking if `k` is non-null, just like `free(NULL)` is allowed.  Having a check inside `freeKey(NULL)` allows for simply calls to it, especially if the higher level code itself is in some error recovery block.

```
void freeKey(Key_t* key) {
  if (key) {  // add
    free (key->buffer);
    free (key);
  }
}
```

Comment: could you add an example for error checking?
i dont get it what you mean with code guards in .h files.
sorry im not so expert in C language

Comment: @Somakun See [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard#Use_of_#include_guards).  Error checking example later.

Comment: ok i got it. i successfully added code guards. you link was really helpful. could you give me help with error checking?

Comment: i also didn't understand what you mean when you talked about free(NULL) well defined

Comment: @Somakun Done..